# Syncing list with XML file

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

Is it possible to sync a SharePoint list with an XML file?
I read about BCS , I don't find any option for XML !

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you using code or want an existing tool? if using code, what language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In BCS, there is no a direct data source for XML file Like SQL Server, meanwhile, you can create an External Content Type based on WCF or a .NET assembly and in your assembly, you could write the code that will read the XML. Check an example at How to: [Create an External Content Type by Writing a .NET Connectivity Assembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee557349%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- Another workaround is to use a 3rd party tool like `Business Data List Connector for SharePoint` for more details check [SharePoint: How to sync external XML data with native lists?](https://www.layer2solutions.com/en/community/FAQs/BDLC/Pages/XML-Sync-to-SharePoint.aspx)
- Check also other workarounds at [Populating a Sharepoint list column from an XML file?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83993/populating-a-sharepoint-list-column-from-an-xml-file)